# Generating Combinations in python

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, combinations, matrix

I am not sure how to go about this in Python, if its even possible.  What I need to do is create an array (or a matrix, or vector?) from 3 separate arrays.  Each array as 4 elements as such, they return this:

Class1 = [1,2,3,4]
Class2 = [1,2,3,4]
Class3 = [1,2,3,4]

Now what I would like to do is return all possible combinations of these three classes.

Example:

1 1 1
 2 1 1
 3 1 1
 4 1 1
 1 2 1
 2 2 1
 3 2 1
 4 2 1...

...and so on to 64 rows (4 elements *16 possible combinations for each class =  64 rows

I am hoping there is a way to do this in python.  I am sure there is but I am not sure what the most efficient way to go about would be.  Perhaps a "for in" loop statement that iterates over each element for each class?  Or now that I am researching this, would itertools handle this?

Thanks in advance for any help offered.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

What you want is called a [Cartesian product](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
import itertools

iterables = [ [1,2,3,4], [88,99], ['a','b'] ]

for t in itertools.product(*iterables):
    print t
```

Answer (score 9):

The simplest way:

```
for i in Class1:
    for j in Class2:
        for k in Class3:
            print (i,j,k)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a cubic approach.

Comment: Is there a way not to be?

Comment: This is the best possible time complexity. In practice itertools might be faster.

Answer (score 2):

Check the Python `itertools` standard [module](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

> **itertools.combinations(iterable, r)**
>
> *Return r length subsequences of elements from the input iterable.*