# Generate combinations from an input in python

Tags: python, generator, combinations

I'm not sure how to go about this in Python. In searching for this, I have come across itertools but I'm not sure how I might apply it in this case.

What I am trying to do is create a script that can take a string input containing query marks (like AB?D?) and a set of options (ABC, DEF) to output all of the possible combinations, like below.

```
ABADD,    ABADE,    ABADF
ABBDD,    ABBDE,    ABBDF
ABCDD,    ABCDE,    ABCDF
```

In searching, I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169825/generating-combinations-in-python) but I'm not entirely sure how I might be able to implement this around my input.

Would it be most efficient to break down the input string into multiple substrings around the question marks (so the above example becomes AB + ? + D + ?). Would something like list (s) be suitable for this?

Thanks in advance for any help offered.

Comment: Are `ABC` and `DEF` fixed to the positions of the corresponding `?`s? Also even though you are not sure of the approach, you should probably share code that you have tried.

Comment: I think this is a simple string replace problem with a for loop so I can write necessary code but you should wait for a while. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to get the combinations and [`string.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to merge those into the template string. (First, replace the `?` with `{}` to get [format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings).)

```
def combine(template, options):
    template = template.replace('?', '{}')
    for opts in itertools.product(*options):
        yield template.format(*opts)
```

Example:

```
>>> list(combine('AB?D?', ['ABC', 'DEF']))
['ABADD', 'ABADE', 'ABADF', 'ABBDD', 'ABBDE', 'ABBDF', 'ABCDD', 'ABCDE', 'ABCDF']
```

Comment: Wow nice compact form and still readable. @534, if it's not clear, the `'{}'` puts placeholders in the generic string to be filled in by the `string.format()` line.