# Format a string with all combinations of multiple dictionary key / values

Tags: python, string, templates, dictionary, format

I'm trying to figure out how, given multiple values, I can generate all combinations of the values when applies to a template / pattern. So if I have the following variables:

```
pattern = '{name} likes {animal}s'
options = {'name': ['Alex', 'Sarah', 'Bob'], 'animal': ['cat', 'dog']}
```

I'd like to have the code print out all the possible combinations based on the string pattern and the values in the dictionary (or any other structure, it doesn't matter)

```
'Alex likes cats'
'Alex likes dogs'
'Sarah likes cats'
'Sarah likes dogs'
'Bob likes cats'
'Bob likes dogs'
```

I can think of some ways do it, but it's messy, and I'm trying to find a way to do this without hardcoding, so in the future I could introduce a new key, like 'color' without having to change anything but `pattern` and `options`

I'm assuming I can use something similar to [this code I found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33065106/380451):

```
def combine(template, options):
    for opts in itertools.product(*options):
        yield template.format(*opts)
```

But I can't figure out how to get all the combinations and keep them in a format that `string.format()` will accept. I'm sure there's some simple solution I'm overlooking.

Comment: Check out itertools product

Comment: you could do a `re.findall` to look for all instances of `\{([^}]\)}' then do an `itertools.product` run of all the keys

Comment: Thanks both, I'll read more up on that to get a better understanding :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I found this out after stumbling upon another question, I'll leave it up in case this helps anyone else:

```
def combine(template, options)
    products = [dict(zip(options, values)) for values in itertools.product(*options.values())]
    return [template.format(**p) for p in products]
```